# Crackling audio due to wrong audio data

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio

I'm using CoreAudio low level API for audio capturing. The app target is MAC OSX, not iOS.

During testing it, from time to time we got very annoying noise modulate with real audio. the phenomena develops with time, started from barely noticeable and become more and more dominant.

Analyze the captured audio under Audacity indicate that the end part of the audio packet is wrong.

Here are sample picture:
[image]

the intrusion repeat every 40 ms which is the configured packetization time (in terms of buffer samples)

Update:
Over time the gap became larger, here is another snapshot from the same captured file 10 minutes later. the gap now contains 1460 samples which is 33ms from the total 40ms of the packet!!
[image]

CODE SNIPPESTS:

capture callback

```
OSStatus MacOS_AudioDevice::captureCallback(void *inRefCon,
                                            AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                            const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                            UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                            UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                            AudioBufferList *ioData)
{
    MacOS_AudioDevice* _this = static_cast<MacOS_AudioDevice*>(inRefCon);

    // Get the new audio data
    OSStatus err = AudioUnitRender(_this->m_AUHAL, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, _this->m_InputBuffer);
    if (err != noErr)
    {
        ...

        return err;
    }

    // ignore callback on unexpected buffer size
    if (_this->m_params.bufferSizeSamples != inNumberFrames)
    {
        ...

        return noErr;
    }

    // Deliver audio data 
    DeviceIOMessage message;
    message.bufferSizeBytes = _this->m_deviceBufferSizeBytes;
    message.buffer = _this->m_InputBuffer->mBuffers[0].mData;
    if (_this->m_callbackFunc)
    {
       _this->m_callbackFunc(_this, message);
    }
}
```

Open and start capture device:

```
void MacOS_AudioDevice::openAUHALCapture()
{
    UInt32 enableIO;
    AudioStreamBasicDescription streamFormat;
    UInt32 size;
    SInt32 *channelArr;
    std::stringstream ss;
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress deviceBufSizeProperty =
    {
        kAudioDevicePropertyBufferFrameSize,
        kAudioDevicePropertyScopeInput,
        kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
    };

    // AUHAL
    AudioComponentDescription cd = {kAudioUnitType_Output, kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput, kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple, 0, 0};
    AudioComponent HALOutput = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &cd);
    verify_macosapi(AudioComponentInstanceNew(HALOutput, &m_AUHAL));

    verify_macosapi(AudioUnitInitialize(m_AUHAL));

    // enable input IO
    enableIO = 1;
    verify_macosapi(AudioUnitSetProperty(m_AUHAL, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 1, &enableIO, sizeof(enableIO)));

    // disable output IO
    enableIO = 0;
    verify_macosapi(AudioUnitSetProperty(m_AUHAL, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &enableIO, sizeof(enableIO)));

    // Setup current device
    size = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);
    verify_macosapi(AudioUnitSetProperty(m_AUHAL, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_CurrentDevice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &m_MacDeviceID, sizeof(AudioDeviceID)));

    // Set device native buffer length before setting AUHAL stream
    size = sizeof(m_originalDeviceBufferTimeFrames);
    verify_macosapi(AudioObjectSetPropertyData(m_MacDeviceID, &deviceBufSizeProperty, 0, NULL, size, &m_originalDeviceBufferTimeFrames));

    // Get device format
    size = sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription);
    verify_macosapi(AudioUnitGetProperty(m_AUHAL, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 1, &streamFormat, &size));

    // Setup channel map
    assert(m_params.numOfChannels <= streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame);
    channelArr = new SInt32[streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame];
    for (int i = 0; i < streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame; i++)
        channelArr[i] = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_params.numOfChannels; i++)
        channelArr[i] = i;

    verify_macosapi(AudioUnitSetProperty(m_AUHAL, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_ChannelMap, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 1, channelArr, sizeof(SInt32) * streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame));
    delete [] channelArr;

    // Setup stream converters
    streamFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    streamFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;
    streamFormat.mFramesPerPacket = m_SamplesPerPacket;
    streamFormat.mBitsPerChannel = m_params.sampleDepthBits;
    streamFormat.mSampleRate = m_deviceSampleRate;
    streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2;
    streamFormat.mBytesPerPacket = streamFormat.mFramesPerPacket * streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame;

    verify_macosapi(AudioUnitSetProperty(m_AUHAL, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &streamFormat, size));

    // Setup callbacks
    AURenderCallbackStruct input;
    input.inputProc = captureCallback;
    input.inputProcRefCon = this;
    verify_macosapi(AudioUnitSetProperty(m_AUHAL, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &input, sizeof(input)));

    // Calculate the size of the IO buffer (in samples)
    if (m_params.bufferSizeMS != -1)
    {
        unsigned int desiredSignalsInBuffer = (m_params.bufferSizeMS / (double)1000) * m_deviceSampleRate;

        // making sure the value stay in the device's supported range
        desiredSignalsInBuffer = std::min<unsigned int>(desiredSignalsInBuffer, m_deviceBufferFramesRange.mMaximum);
        desiredSignalsInBuffer = std::max<unsigned int>(m_deviceBufferFramesRange.mMinimum, desiredSignalsInBuffer);

        m_deviceBufferFrames = desiredSignalsInBuffer;
    }

    // Set device buffer length
    size = sizeof(m_deviceBufferFrames);
    verify_macosapi(AudioObjectSetPropertyData(m_MacDeviceID, &deviceBufSizeProperty, 0, NULL, size, &m_deviceBufferFrames));

    m_deviceBufferSizeBytes = m_deviceBufferFrames * streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame;
    m_deviceBufferTimeMS = 1000 * m_deviceBufferFrames/m_deviceSampleRate;

    // Calculate number of buffers from channels
    size = offsetof(AudioBufferList, mBuffers[0]) + (sizeof(AudioBuffer) * m_params.numOfChannels);

    // Allocate input buffer
    m_InputBuffer = (AudioBufferList *)malloc(size);
    m_InputBuffer->mNumberBuffers = m_params.numOfChannels;

    // Pre-malloc buffers for AudioBufferLists
    for(UInt32 i = 0; i< m_InputBuffer->mNumberBuffers ; i++)
    {
        m_InputBuffer->mBuffers[i].mNumberChannels = 1;
        m_InputBuffer->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize = m_deviceBufferSizeBytes;
        m_InputBuffer->mBuffers[i].mData = malloc(m_deviceBufferSizeBytes);
    }

    // Update class properties
    m_params.sampleRateHz = streamFormat.mSampleRate;
    m_params.bufferSizeSamples = m_deviceBufferFrames;
    m_params.bufferSizeBytes = m_params.bufferSizeSamples * streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame;

}


eADMReturnCode MacOS_AudioDevice::start()
{
    eADMReturnCode ret = OK;
    LOGAPI(ret);

    if (!m_isStarted && m_isOpen)
    {
        OSStatus err = AudioOutputUnitStart(m_AUHAL);
        if (err == noErr)
            m_isStarted = true;
        else
            ret = ERROR;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Any idea what cause it and how to solve?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the process you are using.

Comment: I updated my question with code. Please see above. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like hotpaw2 was right to me.

Comment: If I had something complex, I'd make sure the simplest case works, only then I'd incorporate it into something more complex...
- is the inBusNumber in the AudioUnitRender( ) properly set?
- code seems to render HAL input into  _this->m_InputBuffer.
- what's changing (unexpected) 'buffer size'? is it your proprietary callback?
inNumberFrames might change for a sample or so once in quite a while, unless device sample rate is beeing hot-tweaked.
- is streamFormat what you meant?
- where's m_deviceSampleRate set? In AudioUnitGetProperty()? I see code first getting, then setting the 'stream format'

Answer (score 2):

Periodic glitches or dropouts can be caused by not paying attention to or by not fully processing the number of frames sent to each audio callback.  Valid buffers don't always contain the expected or same number of samples (inNumberFrames might not equal bufferSizeSamples or the previous inNumberFrames in a perfectly valid audio buffer).

It is possible that these types of glitches might be caused by attempting to record at 44.1k on some models of iOS devices that only support 48k audio in hardware.

Some types of glitch might also be caused by any non-hard-real-time code within your m_callbackFunc function (such as any synchronous file reads/writes, OS calls, Objective C message dispatch, GC, or memory allocation/deallocation).

Comment: The target is OSX not iOS. I checking the current device sample rate and configure the stream with actual value. the captured file contain voice in the right sampling rate, not pitch. hence this is not incorrect SR issue

Comment: Please see my updated question, i added the snippet code, as you can see i validate "inNumberFrames" as expected. maybe the are more checks that i need to perform?

Comment: Your capture callback code doesn't appear to process buffers with a different length of frames where your validation fails.  That can produce a dropout.

Comment: When the validation fails, i just drops the packet instead delivering it. BTW, it's happens on routing between devices. How this ignoring can lead to corrupted data in good packets?

Comment: You should never drop packets using Core Audio.  The pull model may pull zeros or garbage on a underrun or dropped packet.  The frame count can change on valid packets.

Comment: When i said dropping frame, it mean not delivering it to my engine for further processing, but immediately return back the thread to it's caller. from OS prospective it's does not matter what i do for the audio data, and it can't know because this is in my buffer. So i not understanding your response. please explain what you think that shuold be done on unexpected size

Comment: All audio unit callback sizes (any, not just bufferSizeSamples) should be expected and thus processed further.  Also, see additions to my answer.

Comment: I found USB device which is happens always and very quickly. from the other side, i put random sleeps in my callback and can't see correlation to this particular issue. if i hold AudioUnit callback i may lose some of audio data but subsequent callback are continues without this kind of problem